# Maze BackTracking using threading

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do a maze traversing, everything is fine except the backtracking part. For the first part, i'm using walk1, walk2 etc to store the points so that i know if it is a valid move (it does not hit a barrier or into a deadend). existPath stores the point that leads to a barrier, currentPath stores the point that is valid, (no barrier, no deadend).

I have this main while loop that only exits when it reaches the end location. But right now for this code, it only backtrack once.

```
Point walk1 = walk;
Point walk2 = walk;
Point walk3 = walk;
Point walk4 = walk;
walk1.x++;
walk2.x--;
walk3.y++;
walk4.y--;

if ( pathObj->isLocationInPath(walk1, existPath) && 
     pathObj->isLocationInPath(walk2, existPath) &&    
     pathObj->isLocationInPath(walk3, existPath) && 
     pathObj->isLocationInPath(walk4, existPath) ||
     ((pathObj->isLocationInPath(walk1, deadEndPath) == 1) &&    
      (pathObj->isLocationInPath(walk2, deadEndPath) ==1) &&
      (pathObj->isLocationInPath(walk3, deadEndPath) == 1) &&  
      (pathObj->isLocationInPath(walk4, deadEndPath) == 1)) )
{
    deadEndPath.push_back(currentPath.back());

    cout << "Thread hits at dead end at ";
    walk.display();
    cout << endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: so.. what is the question?

Comment: 1. Make it work single-threaded. 2. Figure out where/how to use more threads. 3. ???. 4. Profit!

Comment: The first point in @JerryCoffin's comment is really, really important.